# chgrp chown usermod are useless if not root?

Tags: permissions, chown, usermod, chgrp

I am logged under 'achille' 
achille belongs to 2 groups:

```
groups achille 
achille: achille users
```

I want to change the group owner of file 'tree.test' to group 'users'

```
ls -l tree.test
-rw-r--r--. 1 achille achille 2512881 Dec  1 11:53 tree.test
```

I have got full control over my home dir:

```
ls -ld $HOME
drwx------. 15 achille achille 4096 Dec 10 11:51 /home/achille
```

I try:

```
chown :users tree.test
chown: changing group of 'tree.test': Operation not permitted
```

I try:

```
chgrp users tree.test
chgrp: changing group of 'tree.test': Operation not permitted
```

ok, so I decide to have as primary group the group 'users'

usermod command is available to achille, so I use it (right?):

```
usermod -g users achille

usermod: Permission denied.

usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later
```

I log as root to perform this operation (changing primary group)

```
su - 

password:
```

then

```
usermod -g users achille
```

and check it out:

```
id -gn achille 
users
```

then ctrl + D to log back to achille

the file finally  belongs to groups 'users' but the result is bad because my home dir and all files/dirs inside also belong to group users.

I finally found a way (without beeing logged as root) with newgrp command:

```
newgrp users

id -gn 

users

touch file0
```

file0 will have users as group owner

but it looks like newgrp works as long as achille belongs to the group you want to change to otherwise you 've got this error message:

```
newgrp games 

Password: (what password to put here?)

newgrp: failed to crypt password with previous salt: Invalid argument ????
```

so now I am just wondering (and asking), if chgrp,chown,usermod are worth keeping in tools bag beeing an unprivileged user. thanx folks!

Comment: In what directory is your `tree.test` file located and what are the permissions and ownerships of that directory? If it's in your home directory, you also seem to have some sort of extended attribute set on it (the final `.` in the permission string).

Comment: in /home/achille; perm = 700 as stated, file has 644 perm.

Comment: What is the result of `lsattr tree.test`? (by the way, you can change the group of a file you own to anyone of your groups, unless you are using extended attributes OR the filesystem you are working on does not allow it).

Comment: Please add output of `groups` no arguments.

Comment: These are admin tools pretty explicitly. A user doesn't assign groups to themselves. 
 As an example if a user could assign themselves to wheel they'd gain root privileges through sudo on many systems.
These days it's so easy to set up a personal linux box or VM running linux that there's no reason not to learn the admin tools.

Comment: @Eduardo: `lsattr tree.test` gives `------------------ tree.test`

Comment: @davolfman: Obviously, but in this case achille belongs to both 'achille' and 'users' groups.

Comment: @ctrl.alt.delor: output = `achille users`

Comment: shall I conclude the answer to my question is: Yes they are?

Comment: The only reason I can think of for that not to work is a mount point that does not allow setting the group. Inside your home, what is the output of `findmnt -T .`? (that shows the mount point for the current directory)

Comment: @Eduardo: `findmnt -T /home`  <br />

Comment: @achille there is no output ...

Comment: @Eduardo: wait a sec plz, just having issues with comment editing. Basicaly, findmnt says `rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota` on both '/' and '/home'.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this

## The problem

When you add a user to a new group, it just writes some data to a configuration file on the disk. Existing processes are not changed.

## How to solve the problem.

You can logout and back in again, or use `newgrp` to create a new shell process with the new group added (this does the permission checks by reading the data in the file, and then starts a new shell in a new process, with the new group added to the groups).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder exactly what you are looking for. If what you want is to test chown/chgrp operations, you could use [namespaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/135599/ubuntu-can-non-root-user-run-process-in-chroot-jail) to create, from userspace, a *chroot jail*, and then launch privileged processes, within that jail, that create new users and anything else you need.

You can also use [`fakechroot`](https://serverfault.com/a/703775/444698) for the same purpose; it's mentioned in the same question.